# EF6: materializing data using custom type

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Assuming I have an entity:

```
public class Event
{
    ...
    public DateTime At { get; set; }
}
```

As well as a model object:

```
public class Something
{
    ...
    public Date At { get; set; }
}
```

where Date is a custom type which can be implicitly converted from a DateTime:

```
public struct Date
{
    public Date(DateTime value)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
    public static implicit operator Date(DateTime value)
    {
        return new Date(value);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to fetch the data from database into the model:

```
var events = db.Events
    .Select(x => new Something
    {
        ...
        At = x.At,
    })
    .ToList();
```

And of course this is failing with the following exception:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'SMG.Web.Date'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Yes, I know that I could achieve what I need with the help of some temporary object, materialize DateTime value into memory and then convert it into my custom type. But what if I prefer not to use this strategy, and want to do this in one step.

The question is: Is there a way to teach LINQ to Entities how to treat my custom Date on that side of reality?

Comment: Do `ToList()` before the `Select(...)`

Comment: Did you actually read it?

Comment: Yes, which is why I commented instead of answer.

Comment: Yes, forcing data materialization with ToList() and converting it into custom type after this - will help - I know it. But the question is not about the "easy way". I want to know is it possible to do this using my types instead of primitives.

Answer (score 1):

Your cast is the wrong way around. Rewrite it as:

```
public struct Date
{
    public Date(DateTime value)
    {
        DateTimeValue = value;
    }

    // Or whatever your field or property is called
    public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(Date date)
    {
        return date.DateTimeValue;
    }
}
```

Then EF should let you use it in expressions. This approach will not work for code-first EF.

Comment: Did you actually try this in a LINQ-to-Entities query?

Comment: Something similar. Admittedly I used LINQPad to test it, but it generated the correct SQL with EF 6.1.3.

Comment: I would have expected EF to throw an exception because it doesn't know the type `Date`: it's not a mapped type and it's not in its collection of known type mappings. Apparently, it simply tries to assign a DateTime to any property that is mapped to a `DateTime` column in the database and it succeeds when the accepting property succeeds in "swallowing" a `DateTime` value. Of course, this wouldn't work in code-first, because EF wouldn't even be able to create a database column from an unknown type to begin with.